# C# show a form to user if some parameters are not set

Tags: c#, forms, class

I want to create a class which has a function to send email.

I want it to send the email directly, if the relevant properties have been set (this.subject, this.toemail etc.) But if these are not set, I want to show a form to the user (which has some textboxes on it) to fill out these parameters.

I don't know what is the best way of doing this. I also don't know where to start. Could you show me an example or point me somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing concerns.

I suggest you have logic that determines whether all relevant information is present for the email and, if not, displays a form whose sole responsibility is to gather the missing information.

Once the missing information is provided, have your email sending logic go ahead and finish sending the email.

I don't know exactly how your code is structured, but here's a stab at what the pseudo-code might look like.

```
btnSend_Click(...)
{
   EmailSendingClass sender = new EmailSendingClass();
   //  Initialize sender with from, to, etc.
   if (!sender.IsComplete)
   {
       FrmGetMissingFields frm = new FrmGetMissingFields(sender);
   }
   sender.SendEmail();
}
```